# Spring @Async dual behaviour

Tags: java, spring

I have the following class:

```
@Component
public class Foo {

  @Async
  public void test1() {
     ...
  }

  public void test2() {
    test1();
  }
}
```

And another class that has a Foo instance:

```
@Component
public class Bar {

  @Autowired
  public Foo foo;

  public void testMethod() {
    foo.test2();
    foo.test1();
  }
}
```

My experiences are the following: If i call foo.test1() then it runs asynchronously, but if i call foo.test2() - which also calls test1() - then the test1() doesn't run asynchronously. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Async` behavior requires the class to be proxied, and self invocations can't be proxied. Thus, when `test2` calls `test1`, the `@Async` annotation has no effect.

The behavior is described in the [AOP docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies):

> However, once the call has finally reached the target object, the SimplePojo reference in this case, any method calls that it may make on itself, such as this.bar() or this.foo(), are going to be invoked against the this reference, and not the proxy. This has important implications. It means that self-invocation is not going to result in the advice associated with a method invocation getting a chance to execute.